# Jboss Messaging (jbm_tx) table growing

Tags: mysql, jboss, messaging

I am using JBoss-4.2.2.GA with JBM 1.4 and I am seeing the jbm_tx table in the jmsdb schema on MySQL growing.  When I select from the table I can see that there is never more that 5 rows at a time in it.

Why would the table grow to a size, on disk, of over 6GB?  When it did this, my application and database suffered extramly long query times.

Is there any way to prevent the .idb file from getting so large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table files will grow when the data grows, but they may also grow when the changes (insert/update/delete) create gaps between the real contents.
Run this command to tell the cases apart:

mysql> select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, ENGINE, TABLE_ROWS, DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH, DATA_FREE from information_schema.tables ;

(Append "where table_schema = '.....'" to restrict the output to a certain database.)

If you see big values of DATA_FREE, you have gaps. Use "OPTIMIZE TABLE" to get rid of them, see the MySQL documentation for details.